# Do I have to install matplotlib separately from Python 3?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to follow a beginner tutorial on plotting a graph with Python and have typed in the correct code. An error message comes up as follows;

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Does this module have to be installed separately to installing Python, if yes where do I fond the module and how do I install it?

Comment: Yes, it does not come with Python. I would recommend you install a distribution instead of installing your libraries individually. [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) is your best bet.

Comment: Sorry, but http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Searching for "install matplotlib" should have lead you to the correct place

Comment: Upvoting because Peter is new and the question is to whether or not Matplotlib is a part of native Python. How to install it is a separate issue, dependant on the answer to that fundamental question.

Comment: Hi, I went to Anaconda, I could not see a specific download for matplotlib but there was a link to download Python 3.7. If I download that will it include a matplotlib?

Comment: update - I downloaded Python 3 from anaconda and it installed the editor spyder. everything works perfectly so far in graphing various thing with matplotlib. thank you for getting me started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more information for this question. Because you mentioned the Python 3 so let me guess your question.

```
$ pip install matplotlib
$ python3
>>> import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib
```

Is that right? If yes, you should use `pip3` for install `python3` package.

```
$ pip3 install matplotlib
```

If no, maybe you forgot install `matplotlib` and you think that's build-in package? Could you make sure that matplotlib is correctly installed, either if you're on Ubuntu by using

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

or

```
$ pip install matplotlib
```

Update (for windows/anaconda):

Open your Powershell of CMD form your Windows.

```
$ conda install pip
$ pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: Sorry Tran I don't understand your advice. I am on windows and downloaded python 3.7 and IDLE from the Python site. I want to plot graphs but apparently need to download matplotlib. I am in the middle of downloading Python again from Anaconda.

Comment: What they are trying to say is that on some platforms, `pip` only installs the module for Python 2 and you want `pip3` in order to install the module for Python 3. Which OS are you on?

Comment: I don't know who are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Open up a terminal and execute:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `matplotlib` is a third-party module which is not included in the Python standard library.  You need to install it separately in order to be able to use it.

Installation instructions will differ a bit between platforms; your best bet is probably to consult your local Python documentation.  Commonly, `pip3 install matplotlib` or (if you are sure `pip` is the Python 3 version) `pip install matplotlib`; but if you are using a manager like Anaconda etc the arrangements will be slightly different.